# replace symbol-number to gif

Tags: javascript, replace

I need your help.
Here I have text:  `hello #005 goodbye`. 
How to make js replace text starting with `#` by img like `<img src=/img/005.gif>` if `number (005<120)`? I must have something like `hello <img src=/img/005.gif> goodbye`

Comment: So it is a basic regular expression with replace()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In two steps to show process

```js
var str = "hello #005 goodbye",
num = str.match(/\#(\d+) /)[1],
    gif = '<img src="/img/'+num+'.gif" />';
console.log(str.replace("#"+num,gif));
```

One step - test for 3 digits too

```js
var str = "hello #005 goodbye"
      .replace(/\#(\d{3})/,'<img src="/img/$1.gif" />');
console.log(str);
```

With test:

```js
function addGif(str) {
  var num = str.match(/\#(\d+)/),
    gif = num && 
          num.length > 0 && 
          parseInt(num[1]) >= 5 && 
          parseInt(num[1]) <= 120 ? '<img src="/img/' + num[1] + '.gif" />' : "";
  return gif ? str.replace("#" + num[1], gif) : "no number or number not in range";
}
var str = "hello # goodbye"; // will not return a match
console.log(addGif(str))
str = "hello #" // will not return a match
console.log(addGif(str))
str = "hello #005" // will return a match
console.log(addGif(str))
str = "hello #1005" // will not return a match
console.log(addGif(str))
str = "hello #100" // will return a match
console.log(addGif(str))
str = "hello #1111111111 goodbye" // will not return a match
console.log(addGif(str))
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick help!

Comment: Updated to handle either

Comment: thanks, but if a string doesn't contain #005 console tells `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null(…)`

Comment: thanks , but now have another problem: if nothing goes after #005 it returns `no number or number not in range`

Answer (score 1):

Makes no sense to do it in two steps when you can do it in one. The capture group in replace is $1 so you put that where you want the number to go.

```js
var str = "hello #005 goodbye",
    result = str.replace(/#(\d+)/,'<img src="/img/$1.gif" />');
console.log(result);
```

With a check inside the replace with the number requirement I missed the 2 times I read the question!

```js
var str = "hello #005 goodbye",
    result = str.replace(/#(\d{3})/, function (x, group1) {
      var num = parseInt(group1);      
      return num >= 5 && num<=120 ? '<img src="/img/' + group1 + '.gif" />' : group1;
    });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: you are right. but I need to check if num is bigger or smaller then 120 so the previos answer is more useful for me. but still thank you for example

Comment: epascarello LOL

Comment: I see "hello # goodbye" as the result... It would fail for "#11111111" so probably a better reg exp would be `/#(\d{3})\s/`

Comment: thank you. now your answer is much better. marked it as a right one